# Packaging a Mac application for manual install even though it has frameworks?

Tags: macos, installation, packaging, dmg

I'm currently building my first Mac application and I'm a little confused by the delivery process. I've quickly read through the Software Delivery Guide but it seems to imply that if I have several components in my app, I should use a managed install. My application is very simple but it does rely on VVOpenSource frameworks, so when I build my app, beside my .app package, I have 3 .framework directories. I would like to make the installation as simple as possible so a manual install from a DMG would be awesome.

Is there anyway I can package my application in a DMG anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the frameworks inside the Contents/Frameworks directory in your app package.  In order to do that, you need to set the "installation directory" correctly when you build the frameworks, for instance to `@executable_path/../Frameworks/`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please tell me more about where I can find this "installation directory" setting?

Comment: It's a build setting.  Look at the list of build settings in the target info, then scroll down to the Deployment heading or type "installation" in the search field.

Comment: OK, I found the setting, but there's something I don't understand. On which project/target should I set this setting? On my application or on the frameworks that I import into my application?

Comment: The setting is for the frameworks.  (If you have any frameworks that you don't have the source for and have the wrong setting, there is a command line tool `install_name_tool` that can change it.)